# Bogo-sort average runtime explanation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, runtime, average

Can someone please give a thorough explanation of what the average case runtime of bogosort would be?

Psuedocode for the algorithm:

```
while not isInOrder(deck):
    shuffle(deck)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are `n!` permutations, only one of which is correct (assuming distinct elements).  So in a hand-waving sense, you would expect to select the right answer after about `O(n!)` iterations.<sup>*</sup>  But each shuffle/check operation is itself `O(n)`.  Hence `O(n.n!)` overall.

---

<sub>* To be precise, you can model as a [*geometrically-distributed random variable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter *p = 1/n!*.  The expected value of such a variable is *1/p = n!*.</sub>

Comment: Assuming uniform distribution it would take `n!/2` attempts in average, not `n!`, not that it changes the complexity

Comment: @icepack I disagree. The expected number of attempts is `n!`

Comment: If you were to sort 2 elements, the expected number of attempts is _not_ 1.

Comment: @JanDvorak it's probabilistic rather than deterministic. You have 50% chance to hit the correct permutation during the first `n!/2` attempts and 50% chance to hit it during the last `n!/2` attempts. On average you'll get the it after `n!/2` attempts.

Comment: @icepack that's only true if you remember what shuffles you have already attempted. If you don't the number of attempts is unbounded.

Comment: @icepack: Actually, that's not true.  It's the geometric distribution (which I can't remember how to use), so I'm going to not bother calculating it, and cheat!

Comment: @JanDvorak That's true for any probabilistic algorithm.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yep, you're right - it's something of that kind :) But I think more important is to understand that it's not `n!`

Comment: @icepack if you don't remember your attemts, it _is_ `n!`

Comment: @icepack: After some brief revision of something I last touched 10 years ago, it turns out it **is** n!.  The expected value of a geometrically-distribution variable is 1/p.

Comment: Haven't touched this stuff for years too... Not sure about the geometric distribution here. Seems like there is some more advanced math involved - at least that's what wiki claims

Comment: @icepack: Each iteration is a Bernoulli trial, with probability of success 1/n!.  Geometric distribution just tells you the probability that you need `k` Bernoulli trials to achieve one success.

Answer (score 1):

The average number of attempts to perform an operation is inverse to the probability each attempt succeeds.

There are `n!` ways to shuffle `n` elements. If all elements are distinct, only one way produces a sorted output. Thus, the probability of a sorting shuffle is `1/n!` and the average number of attempts is `n!`.

Each shuffle takes `O(n)` time (assuming Fisher-Yates shuffle or anything equally reasonable).

Thus, the time complexity is `O(n!*n)`.

Comment: @icepack not sure about the equality, but `O((n+1)!)` is a superset of `O(n!*n)`. I didn't think it worth including in the answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yep, they're equivalent, (n+1)! = (n+1)n! = (n! + n.n!).

Comment: last step: `n*n! < n*n!+n! < 2n*n!`

Comment: Just take limit of (n + 1)! / n.n! for n approaches inf, the result is a finite number (1), so they are equivalent classes of functions.